# Autoloading in Child Theme

Tags: php, functions, composer, autoloading

I'm trying to autoload the vendor/autoload.php from my parent theme into my child theme.

heres what i have tried but to no avail:

```
function beast_theme_setup() {
  $var1 = get_theme_root_uri() . '/beast/vendor/autoload.php';
  $var2 = get_theme_root_uri() . '/beast/functions.php';
  $var = locate_template( array( $var1, $var2), true, false );
  var_dump($var);
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'beast_theme_setup', 11 );
```

and

```
include get_theme_root_uri() . '/beast/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Any help on this would be amazing.

Thanks Jake.

Comment: You're using a composer autoloader? where is the project root? Are you the one running composer install, or is this intended to be packaged up and sent elsewhere? You can use `get_template_directory` to get the parent theme folder path

Comment: @TomJNowell [File structure](http://imgur.com/a/ukvYg), yes i'm the one running composer install, get_template_directory seems to only get the child-theme link as i want to require the parent functions.php file / autoload.php file in the child theme

Comment: `get_template_directory` should refer to the parent theme, and `get_stylesheet_directory` should give you the child theme, assuming you've correctly created a child theme. I would avoid using locate_template for non-template files, it's intended for `get_template_part`, and a composer autoloader is not a template

Comment: Judging from your autoloader setup, you have a main composer.json and vendor folder at the top level, so an mu-plugin that loads that autoloader would be the way to do it, your theme folders shouldn't have vendor folders in that setup, unless you've been running composer install in multiple places

Comment: @TomJNowell the composer.json at root level just installs [WordPress through composer](https://packagist.org/packages/johnpbloch/wordpress), then in the parent theme there are packages like Timber / Kirki / tgmpa etc that i dont want to mess with in the child theme, they should be untouched and left in the parent theme until an update is required. What code shall i use for the mu-plugin?? also is there any way to check if the autoloader is working?

Comment: You can specify an exact version for those in the parent themes `composer.json`, then add both the parent and child as dependencies along with WordPress in your main composer.json. Remember, packages don't need to know where they are or how they're installed, just that they're there, and to load an autoloader if it's present, and trust it'll be loaded elsewhere if it isn't

Comment: @TomJNowell, i've re read your answer below, so do you think that it would be best to install everything on root level like Timber / Kirki etc and then require it into my parent -> child theme heres the root composer.json file [Root composer.json](http://imgur.com/a/Iap7s), if yes how would be best do it? The current link the the autoloader is in the wp-config.php in the public folder like this -> `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: The location of composer packages is irrelevant, loading them is the autoloaders job, and packages should make no assumptions about their own location or that of their dependencies. Dependencies that are WordPress plugins and themes being the exception, but this is getting broader in scope, and may be better as a new question

Answer (score 9):

So there are one or two things to keep in mind:

- There should only be 1 vendor folder
- There should be a primary composer.json that's in your project root, that would pull in all the dependencies
- You always check for and load the autoloader in the current directory, there's no guarantee it is or isn't there as you may or may not be a dependency yourself

But importantly, there's more information about WP themes you need to know that simplify your task:

Firstly, `get_theme_root` isn't necessary, you can use `get_template_directory()` instead, and it will give you the parent theme directory, so no hardcoding the parent themes name.

This should simplify your code to this:

```
if ( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

But even this isn't necessary, which brings us to the second piece of information:

In WordPress, the child themes `functions.php` is loaded, then the parent themes `functions.php` immediately afterwards.

So all you need to do is make sure that the parent theme loads the autoloader, and that all your code is ran on actions as it should be ( except the autoloader itself ). This way you don't need to load the parent themes autoloader at all, it will do it itself